# An strange triple integral I've never seen before

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

This is one of the integrals I have for homework, But I've never seen anything like this before, I don't know what to do with it. Does anyone know?

> $$\int_0^1 dz \int_z^1 dx \int_0^x e^{x^2} dy.$$

**UPDATE**

although $$\int_0^x e^{x^2} dy$$ is easy to handle. But there is definitely something about this integral as the teacher has already mentioned it. If we have:

> $$\int_0^1 dz \int_z^1 dxxe^{x^2}.$$

$$xe^{x^2}=\frac {d(\frac {e^{x^2}}{2})} {dx} \Rightarrow dx= \frac {d(\frac {e^{x^2}}{2})} {x{e^{x^2}}}\Rightarrow $$
$$\int_0^1 dz \int_z^1 dxxe^{x^2}=\int_0^1 dz \int_z^1 d(\frac {e^{x^2}}{2})=\int_0^1 dz(\frac {e}{2}-\frac {e^{z^2}}{2})...$$
could it be right?

Comment: In which parts are you get stuck?

Comment: This looks like "the multiplication of $\int_0^1dz$ by $\int_z^1dx$ and $\int_0^xe^{x^2}dy$."  Do you have any examples of similar problems available to check against?

Comment: I think a pretty obvious difficulty with this integral is the difficulty of integrating $e^{x^2}$. The OP then probably doesn't realize he or she should try switching the order of integration.

Comment: @nayrb: to me, $\int_0^xe^{x^2}dy$ is very easy: $xe^{x^2}$.  I'm not sure I understand your comment...

Comment: @abiessu, whoops, misread the order of integration. I assume that this was a trickier integral than it is.

Comment: @abiessu By the way, that notation is (horribile dictu) used by some to indicate nested integrals, it means $$\int_0^1 \left(\int_{z}^1 \left(\int_0^x e^{x^2}\,dy \right)\,dx \right)\,dz.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer: ah, that makes more sense now, and thus the obvious problem of $e^{x^2}$ is resolved easily.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^1 dz \int_z^1 dx \int_0^x e^{x^2} dy = \int_0^1 dz \int_z^1 e^{x^2} dx \int_0^x dy $
= $\int_0^1 dz \int_z^1 e^{x^2} x$ dx
= $\int_0^1 (\frac{e}{2} - \frac{e^{z^2}}{2}) dz$
= $\int_0^1 \frac{e}{2} dz- \int_0^1\frac{e^{z^2}}{2}dz $
= $\frac{e}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$